# how to install and connect jdbc driver in adt bundle?

Tags: android

can we install jdbc in adt bundle. if yes tell me how install jdbc driver in adt bundle and create connection. I have oracle 11g R2 in my computer running with windows 8. Thanks for your suggestions in advance..

Answer (score 0):

- First of all please add the Android Tag as it is an Android Developer
  Tools question.
- Second as you know you  are working on the ADT you must be understanding
  that it's just a special bundle of Eclipse which is devoted for
  purely android application development.(Eclipse supports various platforms regarding development).
- Third download the required package from the
  [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/downloads/index.html)
- Fourth Integrate it with the ADT
  Lastly if you still don't get any idea try this link as the last alternative [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_03/html/installation/build_android_jdbc.html)